# In protractor, Select an element by 2 attributes

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, protractor

How can I select an element using 2 attributes.

For example:

```
<div data-button="1" data-column="13" style="margin-right: 5px;" id="0"></div>
```

I want to find element with data-column="13" and id="0"
Now I select by one element:

```
var element = $('div[data-button="1"]');
```

Comment: Using xpath `by.xpath("//div[@data-column='13' and @id='0']")`

Answer (score 1):

Best bet i would place on is to use `css` selector first, as its fast and easier to understand. Here's how to use it -

```
var element = $('div#0[data-button="1"]');
```

Alternatively you can also use `xpath` to get it. @Jason has already mentioned one example in the comment above. Here's another way -

```
var element = element(by.xpath('//div[@id="0"][@data-button="1"]'));
```

Hope it helps.